# Rx read File and send data to 12 observer

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

#### explain last code:

before i use below code to read and send this date white handler.
code read binary file allocated 8 * 12 * 1002 byte that is signal data( Contains
12*1002 double value)

#### question:

how can i use rx_java2 to read this file and stream
Looping ,synchronous  every 1002 double synchronous to 12 observer that publish double value  with delay every 2 ms

```
class readFile {


public fun getBuffer(sigId: String): ArrayList<DoubleArray> {

    
  val address="/data/data/com.example.amin.ecgs/Signals/Sig$sigId.bin"
    lateinit var buf: DoubleBuffer
    try {

        val rFile = RandomAccessFile(address, "rw")
        val inChannel = rFile.channel
        val buf_in = ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * 12 * 1002)
        buf_in.clear()
        inChannel.read(buf_in, 0)
        buf_in.rewind()
        buf = buf_in.asDoubleBuffer()

        inChannel.close()

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()

    }

    return generateData(buf)

}

private fun generateData(buf: DoubleBuffer): ArrayList<DoubleArray> {

    val arrayList = ArrayList<DoubleArray>(12)

    for (n in 0..11) {
        val yb = DoubleArray(1002)
        buf.get(yb, n * 1002, (n + 1) * 1002)

        arrayList.add(yb)

    }
    buf.clear()
    return arrayList
}


}
```

Comment: why do you need to observe this data 12 times simultaneously

Comment: @TimCastelijns i want  publish every 1002 double value to Separate observe (12 graph view) ,  don want all value observe 12 time (values Contains 12*1002 double value)

Comment: in theory you could have 1 subject where you send all the data to, and have 12 callers observe that subject

Answer (score 0):

You can try `concat` operation with by creating each `Observable` or create something from `Observable.fromIterator()` as shown. Note that the error handling becomes tricky when you do this and when you have to handle error downstream. It would be better to use `Flowable` because of the `BackPressureStrategy` that you can define with `onErrorResumeNext` if you want continue with the next array if incase one of them fail.

```
public class ReadBinaryDate extends Thread {

    final ArrayList<Observable<double[]>> doubleObservables = new ArrayList<>();

    private Observable<double[]> generateObservable (final double [] array1002) {
        return Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<double[]>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<double[]> apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.just(array1002);
                }
            });
    }

    private void generateData() {

        arrayList.clear();
        for (int n = 0; n < 12; n++) {
            double[] yb = new double[1002];
            buf.get(yb, n*1002, (n+1)*1002);
            doubleObservables.add(generateObservable(yb));
        }
    }

    private void subscribeStream() {
        Observable.fromIterable(doubleObservables)
            .subscribe(new Observer<Observable<double[]>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) { }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Observable<double[]> observable) {
                    // do on each array
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // handle error
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    // do on complete
                }
            });
    }
}
```